# When adding new product, Auto Increase the price of 10% in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, vendor

I am using the following code in my WordPress site to increase the product price by 10%. It works fine but the issue is that the price is updated every time by 10% when making any edit in the product. I want it increases the price by 10% only when adding a new product.

I am using [WC Marketplace](https://wordpress.org/plugins/dc-woocommerce-multi-vendor/) plugin. The code works in the vendor side but not in the WordPress admin panel.

Here is the code I am using:

```
function get_price_multiplier() { 
    return get_option(10); 
} 

// Simple, grouped and external products
add_filter('woocommerce_product_get_price', 'custom_price', 99, 2 );  
add_filter('woocommerce_product_get_regular_price', 'custom_price', 99, 2 ); 
// Variations
add_filter('woocommerce_product_variation_get_regular_price', 'custom_price', 99, 2 ); 
add_filter('woocommerce_product_variation_get_price', 'custom_price', 99, 2 ); 
function custom_price( $price, $product ) { 
    $price_per = round($price * get_price_multiplier()/100);
    return round($price + $price_per); 
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This will only add the amount  showing the price - it will never update the product

Comment: I want this will update price when I am adding new product not while editing existing product.

Comment: Its the filter to alter price while showing - it will not update the price into database - I think you are on wrong hook - Or your question is not clear